# OleDbPermission and ASP.NET medium trust

Tags: asp.net, hosting, oledb, medium-trust

I'm following [this document in order to run my website in a medium trust environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx). My web app uses OleDb, so I need to give it permission in medium trust. I've done everything that is in that article and it's still not working :(

In my web_mediumtrust.config I've added the following security class:

```
<SecurityClass Name="OleDbPermission" Description="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

And the following permission set:

```
<PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Name="ASP.Net">
   <IPermission class="OleDbPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
</PermissionSet>
```

But I still get an exception when I try to use it:

> System.Security.SecurityException
>   occurred   Message="Request for the
>   permission of type
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission,
>   System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed."   Source="mscorlib"
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean isPermSet)
>          at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection blah blah blah....

Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to do anything else?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a configuration folder for x32:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\CONFIG
```

and another for x64:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\{version}\CONFIG
```

I feel such as stupid...